# Powershell: evaluate math expression represented as string

Tags: powershell, string, calculator, bc

In PowerShell, how do I evaluate a mathematical expression stored as a string? How do I get PowerShell to evaluate the following:

```
C:\> $a="30000/1001"
C:\> $a

30000/1000
C:\>
```

Desired output:

```
C:\> $a="30000/1001"
C:\> <some command>

29.97002997003
C:\>
```

In Linux I could do the following (and is basically what I want to accomplish in PowerShell):

```
user@computer:/path# a="30000/1001"
user@computer:/path# echo "scale=5; $a" | bc
29.97002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7). Alternatively just invoke a new shell (much slower of course)

```
$a="30000/1001"
Invoke-Expression $a
powershell -Com $a
```

Comment: Thank you! I was at a loss of what keywords to google and it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Using Invoke-Expression is generally [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/avoidusinginvokeexpression?view=ps-modules); I suggest a safer approach using `System.Data.DataTable` instead:

```
$a="30000/1001"
[Data.DataTable]::New().Compute($a, $null)
# Result = 29.97002997003
```